# How to read an excel file with multiple sheets using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is what i try

```py
from pathlib import Path
loc = Path('D:\DataSciSpec\Practice\Forloopindict.xlsx')
dict = pd.read_excel(loc,sheetname = None)

for i in dict.keys():
    print(i)
```

I get the name of sheets

Sheet4
Sheet3
Sheet2
Sheet1

I can also see the sheet content one by one

```py
for i in dict.keys():
    print(dict[i].head())
```

But how put this data in n data frames (equal to no of sheets)
and then append one to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a single dataframe (df_full) with the data from all sheets.

```
import pandas as pd

loc = r'D:\DataSciSpec\Practice\Forloopindict.xlsx'
workbook = pd.read_excel(loc,sheet_name = None)
df_full = pd.DataFrame()
for _, sheet in workbook.items():
    df_full = df_full.append(sheet)

# Reset index or you'll have duplicates
df_full = df_full.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I don't think this would constitute a separate answer, because I'd just be copy-pasting a lot of your code. That said, `for _, sheet in workbook.items(): df_full = df_full.append(sheet)` would be the most normal, and possibly slightly more efficient, way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! learnt that "_" is a variable that is not used